# How to pass shell wildcards into a backtick command

Tags: shell, wildcard, backticks

I am trying to use find in a shell script to count the number of files I have matching a wildcard pattern, then to get the name of the file if there is only one. But I'm having trouble passing the wildcard pattern through to backtick expansion.

```
FINDCMD="find . -iname *DATA*.txt"
DATACOUNT=$($FINDCMD | wc -l)

if [ $DATACOUNT -eq 1 ]
then
  use-data $($FINDCMD)
else
  echo bugger
fi
```

That doesn't work: the shell expands *DATA*.txt at the time of calling find. I want the asterisks to be passed to find.

If I make it

```
FINDCMD="find . -iname '*DATA*.txt'"
```

Then the shell doesn't expand the asteriks, but find gets the single-quotes and matches nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put your commands in a variable. What's wrong with just executing the command directly?

```
DATACOUNT=$(find . -iname "*DATA*.txt" | wc -l)
if [ $DATACOUNT -eq 1 ];then
    .....
fi
```

Edit:

if you wan to reuse the command, use a subroutine

```
myfind(){
    find . -iname "*DATA*.txt" | wc -l
}
```

Comment: Because I want to reuse the same command to get the filename, if there is only one. Better for maintainability to have the command defined in only one place. But if I have to, I can do it like you suggest. There must be a better way..

Answer (score 1):

Do BOTH of following:

1. Use quotes in find command: `FINDCMD="find . -iname \"*DATA*.txt\""` OR `FINDCMD='find . -iname "*DATA*.txt"'`
2. Use following bash option: `-f      Disable pathname expansion.` as follows `set -f` in the beginning of the script

That should do the trick. Not tested on your script though, but you should get the idea from this point.

Answer (score -1):

Switch the single and double quotes.

Try:

```
FINDCMD='find . -iname "*DATA*.txt"'
```

Comment: Did you try this? this seems to not help at all. finds nothing.

Comment: i tried both and they seem to act the same unfortunately. they dont match any file,